# _doPostBack passing parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

I am trying to pass a parameter from JQuery to C# using the _doPostBack(), however for some reason, I am not managing to capture the actual parameter.

My JQuery is as follows :-

```
    function SearchText() {
    $("#persons").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "JQAutoComplete2.aspx/FetchPersons",
                data: "{'name':'" + document.getElementById('persons').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                    var val = document.getElementById('persons').value;
                    _doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', val);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: '', results: function () {
            }
        }

    });
}
```

and my code-behind is as follows :-

```
        protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var value = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];


        RadGrid1.DataSource = ctx.GetDataFromXML(false, 0);
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
    }
```

Although this method is called, the val is not passed to the method, and the EventArgument remains "".

I tried Request.Forms["_*EVENTARGUMENT"], also Request["*_EVENTARGUMENT"] but still I get an empty string.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Check this - before `__doPostBack` should be TWO underscores!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client-side:

__doPostBack('id', 'value');

As sll mentioned => **two** underscores

On server-side:

```
Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]
```

Here also **two** underscores

You wrote you tried already Request["_EVENTARGUMENT"] => but you are not using two underscores!